# deploying multiple struts apps in jboss problem

Tags: deployment, jboss, struts2

I m trying to deploy two struts2 projects(ear files) in jboss 4.2.2GA.When i deploy them seperately they work fine, but if i deploy them together i get the following error

**Unable to load configuration. - action -file:/C:/jboss.........struts.xml:60:109**

however one of the project works fine.For the other one, welcome page is loaded but none of the actions are performed.It shows this error

**HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name loginAction**

I tried changing package name defined in struts.xml, but no luck

what could be th reason?Do i need to change any configuration in jboss or struts.xml

Comment: Sound's like a parsing error line 60:character 109(although I've found they are often way off), I can't see how it could load either but then not parse if both are there. Trim struts.xml (no actions) and see if it will run, if it does then I guess we'll need to see more of the xml.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you said i trimmed the action mappings, now it doesn't shows the configuration error but the 404 error for actions is there (for obvious reasons). Does that means there is something wrong in my action mappings. Its strange because when i deploy a single application at a time the action on the line(60) as mentioned in the error works fine. I also should have mentioned that many of my action names and mappings are identical in the two struts.xml files

Comment: Another thing which i noticed is that till line 60(that is shown in the error) both of the struts file are exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,finally i made it to work. This [post](http://www.jroller.com/bsnyder/entry/jboss_unified_classloader_hell_docs) helped me.I added jboss-app.xml file in both of my applications with following content

```
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository> 
    com.adc.advertiser:loader=application1.ear 
  </loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

same for application2.ear
Also in jboss-servie.xml present in deploy directory i changed Java2ClassLoadingCompliance and UseJBossWebLoader to false